# How to calculate white area with Python and Opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I am triyng calculate the area of the white pixels in this image:

[image]

My code :

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("tepsi.jpg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,(21, 10, 15), (30, 255, 255) )
cv2.imshow("orange", mask)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How can I solve this problem? Actually my purpose is to find empty areas of food tray.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Use `whitePixelCount = cv2.countNonZero(mask)` to get the count of the **white pixels** in your mask. The function will count every pixel that is white, including the ones that are isolated from other blobs. If you want a percentage, divide `whitePixelCount` by the mask dimensions.

Comment: Since shape of  tray is fixed, you can divide locations(five position of dishes and blank) first and apply threshold then(cv2.inrange). That will probably show better results.

Comment: Or if you have to get blank area using only color space. I think adaptive threshold function is better than fixed thresholds.

Answer (score 4):

[image]Thanks for your advices, i found a solution for my problem for above picture. But i will try your advices...

Note: My tray is white area and it is constant for now.

My solution :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("petibor_biskuvi.png")
dimensions = image.shape

height= image.shape[0]
width = image.shape[1]
size = height*width

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)


_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

cnts, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
size_elements = 0
for cnt in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image,cnts, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    size_elements += cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    print(cv2.contourArea(cnt))



cv2.imshow("Image", image)
print("size elements total : ", size_elements)
print("size of pic : ", size)
print("rate of fullness : % ", (size_elements/size)*100)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one option. Since white in BGR is `(255, 255, 255)`, id suggest you convert the image to a boolean true where each (independent) channel equals to `255`:

```
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
wb = b == 255
wg = g == 255
wr = r == 255
```

The value of all of the channels must be `255` (`True`) for the same pixel, so, use [np.bitwise_and](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html):

```
white_pixels_if_true = np.bitwise_and(wb, np.bitwise_and(wg, wr))
```

Finally, get the count of the true value and the size of the image and find the percentage of white pixels:

```
img_size = r.size
white_pixels_count = np.sum(white_pixels_if_true)
white_area_ratio = white_pixels_count / img_size
```

Given the area of the image you can multiply the area by the `white_area_ratio` to get the white area.